# Backpropagation on a 2 hidden layer Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to make my first Neural Network, and I've tried to make one with 2 hidden layers, but it's not learning.

I'm pretty sure the feedforward part is working fine, but no matter how much I train it(with a XOR table), the error doesn't decrease, it just oscillates around 0.5. I guess there's something wrong with the backpropagation part, but I've revised it many times and even calculated what it should be to no avail.

Here's the code:

```py
class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):

        # Sets the input and output sizes
        self.inputs  = input_size
        self.outputs = output_size

        # Sets size of hidden layers
        self.L1 = 2
        self.L2 = 2

        # Initializes weights
        self.W1 = np.random.rand(self.inputs.shape[1], self.L1)
        self.W2 = np.random.rand(self.L1, self.L2)
        self.W3 = np.random.rand(self.L2, self.outputs.shape[1])


    # The network evaluates the inputs
    def feedforward(self, inp):

        self.inputs = inp

        # Evaluates layer 1
        Z1 = sig(np.dot(self.inputs, self.W1))

        # Evaluates layer 2
        Z2 = sig(np.dot(Z1, self.W2))

        # Evaluates end result
        Z3 = sig(np.dot(Z2, self.W3))

        self.outputs = Z3

    # Backpropagation
    def train(self, inp, outp):

        # Evaluate the input
        self.inputs = inp

        # Evaluates layer 1
        Z1 = sig(np.dot(self.inputs, self.W1))

        # Evaluates layer 2
        Z2 = sig(np.dot(Z1, self.W2))

        # Evaluates end result
        Z3 = sig(np.dot(Z2, self.W3))

        # Evaluate the error
        error = Z3 - outp

        print("Error: " +  str(abs(error.sum())))

        # Backpropagates
        dcost_dpred = error
        dpred_dz = dsig(np.dot(Z2, self.W3))

        z_delta = dcost_dpred * dpred_dz
        self.W3 -= lr * np.dot(Z2.T, z_delta)

        z_delta = np.dot(z_delta, self.W3.T)
        self.W2 -= lr * (np.dot(Z1.T, z_delta) * dsig(np.dot(Z1, self.W2)))

        z_delta = np.dot(z_delta, self.W2.T)
        self.W1 -= lr * (np.dot(self.inputs.T, z_delta) * dsig(np.dot(self.inputs, self.W1)))
```

Is it really wrong? If it is, how should I fix it?

Comment: use some not-random values at start and calculate all on paper and then use the same values at start in Python - and then you may compare result from code with result from paper.

Comment: @furas, I just did exactly that, and weirdly they are working fine. I thought that maybe it wasn't working because I changed the weights before calculating the variation of the next weights, so I calculated all the variations before updating the weights, but it still isn't working.